# Xamarin forms open browser and get Response data

Tags: http, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to open a website in my mobile app to make the user log in to a specific page (so he can trust that it's the real website), if the login succeeds, there is data in the response which I need for my application. Is there a way to get the response data from the `Xamarin.Essentials` `WebView` or `Browser` or something else?

Some additional Information after Juan Sturla's hint:

I've got this url:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.realm=https://MYAPP&
openid.return_to=https://MYAPP/signin/
```

This link refers to the Steam login page. Can I somehow tell the Authenticator to return to the app after logging in ***without*** setting up a Backend? Like is it somehow possible to magically bind the app as return URL? I'm on iOS btw.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I guess that you are looking for [Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator), also from Xamarin.Essentials

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks promising. But: I do need an ASPNET Backend for this to work right?

Comment: this is probably a violation of Steam's TOS